# Json generated Object Graph query using Linq?

Tags: linq, json, serialization

I'm working with a json file containing the following:

```
{
"objects":[ 
        {"object": 1, 
            "data":{
                "name": "object 1",
                "priority_threshold": "6000", 
                "email_threshold": "2000"
        }},
        {"object": 3,
            "data":{
                "name": "object 3",
                "priority_threshold": "5000",
                "email_threshold": "2000"
        }},
        {"object": 5,
            "data":{
                "name": "object 5",
                "priority_threshold": "5000",
                "email_threshold": "1000"
        }},
        {"object": 6,
            "data": {
                "name": "object 6",
                "priority_threshold": "4000",
                "email_threshold": "2000"
        }
    }
]}
```

the .json file is an embedded file and is being returned as a string.

Then from the string I am deserializing the object using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer to do the following:

```
Dictionary<string, object> toConfigGraph = (Dictionary<string, object> toSerializer.DeserializeObject(psJsonString);
object[] toEventServiceConfig = (object[])toConfigGraph["objects"];
```

The problem running into is that I only want to return the data for a particular object using the object ID, but I'm unsure as to the best process.  The I would like to implement a Linq solution, but as of now I'm not even sure if that will work since toConfigGraph["applications"] returns an array of objects based on the structure of the json.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I'd rather NOT have to iterate through the object array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        Dictionary<string, object> toObj = (Dictionary<string, object>)toEventServiceConfig.Where(o => Int32.Parse(((Dictionary<string, object>)o)["object"].ToString()) == 1).First<object>();
        Dictionary<string, object> toData = (Dictionary<string, object>)toObj["data"];
```

Comment: Thank you Mutt... you are a Linq god.